# How do you get this result, using Jquery Scroll Event & offset/position, css or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do you get this result in css, javascript or jquery, or a combination of all:

[image]

I asked and posted a similar question before, but no one answered it.
Someone said:

```
"Maybe you can use javascript (or bether JQuery) for this.

If you use JQuery, you can use the scroll event. If you are scrolling, do a 
check if it hits the other div. https://api.jquery.com/scroll/

Checking the positions of the divs is possible with offset/position.     
http://api.jquery.com/offset/ https://api.jquery.com/position/

If you want to change the background, you give the div a background color  
that is pink. If it hits then you can add an additional background-image   
that has a specific background-position 
(http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp xpos ypos).


 I don't have tried it yet, but I guess it is possible that way."
```

So my question is, how would you go about doing it to get this result or regardless of what way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with this after a couple of hours trying to make it work. It was pretty fun doing it, so I'm sharing it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var initScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
$('.div1').css('top', (initScrollTop+100)+"px");

$(window).scroll(function () {
    var top = parseInt($('.div1').css('top').split("px")[0]);

    // I GIVE A FIXED TOP TO .DIV1
    var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop() + 100;
    $('.div1').css('top', scrollTop+"px");

    // GETTING SOME VALUES

    // DIV1
    var div2Top = parseInt($('.div2').css('top').split('px')[0]);
    var div2Height = parseInt($('.div2').css('height').split('px')[0]);
    var div2Bottom = parseInt($('.div2').css('bottom').split('px')[0]);

    // DIV2 
    var div1Width = parseInt($('.div1').css('width').split('px')[0]);
    var div1Height = parseInt($('.div1').css('height').split('px')[0]);
    var div1Top = parseInt($('.div1').css('top').split('px')[0]);
    var div1Bottom = parseInt($('.div1').css('bottom').split('px')[0]);
    var div1Left = parseInt($('.div1').css('left').split('px')[0]);

    // WE ARE GOING THROUGH THE GREEN BOX
    if(scrollTop + div1Height > div2Top) {


        // OUTSIDE OF THE GREEN BOX (.div2)
        if(scrollTop + div1Height > div2Height + div2Top) {


           var div3Height = div2Top + div2Height - scrollTop;
            $('.div3').css('top', scrollTop+ "px")
                     // .css('bottom', div2Bottom + "px")
                      .css('width', div1Width + "px")
                      .css('height', div3Height + "px")
                      .css('visibility','visible');
                      console.log("I'm out");
        } 

        // INSIDE OF THE GREEN BOX (.div2)
        else {

            var div3Height = (div1Top > div2Top) ? div1Height : scrollTop + div1Height - div2Top;
            var div3Top = (div1Top > div2Top) ? div1Top : div2Top;
            $('.div3').css({
                'top' : div3Top + "px",
                'left': div1Left + "px",
                'width': div1Width + "px",
                'height': div3Height + "px",
                'visibility':'visible'
                });

        }

    } else { 
        $('.div3').css('visibility','hidden');
    }


    // WE ARE ABSOLUTELY OUT OF THE GREEN BOX (FROM THE BOTTOM GOING DOWN)
    if(scrollTop > div2Top + div2Height) {
      $('.div3').css('visibility','hidden');   
    }


}); 
});
```

Here's there a fiddle so you can test it http://jsfiddle.net/5076h670/2/

So basically what it does is create three divs, two of them will be visible and 'collide' between each other, the other one starts hidden and it shows only when the position of the `div1` is in the range of the `div2`. This `div3` (the third div) will be shown over the `div1` (see the `z-index`). When it's absolutely out of the box `div3` will be hidden.

I don't know what else to explain about the code, I don't know if (and I don't think, it took me a while to make it work) it's understandable what it does. If you have something to ask I'll be reading ;)

Hope it helps

Comment: one more thing, everything is great, however I have just 1 problem. http://jsfiddle.net/5076h670/5/

Notice when div1 goes above div2, the width doesn't automatically adjust to div2, if you understand what I mean from the fiddle I linked.

how would I fix that? so essentially the height is great, how would I get the width to the same thing? possible?

Comment: That's because I made the `div3`'s width to adjust to `div1`'s width and in the CSS you modified the `div1` with to 700px. You can do two things : 1. Change wherever I passed `div1Width` to `div2Width` (and add the `div2Width` because I didn't use it so I didn't add it), or 2. Change in the CSS the width of `div1`  to match the `div2` width.